# Getting `Enter APP_SCOUT_HANG state` in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, terminal, warnings, delay, flutter-pubspec

SPECIFICATION (NEW)

```
Flutter version 3.13.2
JDK version 17.0.6+0
Dart version 3.1.0
```

SPECIFICATION (OLD)

```
Flutter version (but I think it is on 3.3.3)
JDK version (unknown)
Dart version (I think it is on dart 2)
```

This project I got it from my partner and they need to do some maintenance from the old version to the new version and add some maps page, but there is something happened, while I running the app I get the delay for it and the terminal said "Hang State" or something like that, and to be honest there is a lot of warning and I don't know what can I do and where are the problems.

And these are the summary from terminal Dialog

```
W/MIUIScout App(31798): Enter APP_SCOUT_WARNING State

W/MIUIScout App(31798): Event:APP_SCOUT_WARNING Thread:main backtrace:
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at  

com.wongpiwat.trust_location.LocationAssistant.checkInitialLocation(LocationAssistant.java:494)

com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)

I/e.mobilebenerit(31798): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
W/MIUIScout App(31798): Enter APP_SCOUT_HANG state
W/MIUIScout App(31798):  (Current message: duration=5003ms seq=31 late=4ms h=com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$CallbackHandler w=1)
D/AppScoutStateMachine(31798): dump trace dirName = com.example.mobilebenerit-31798-APP_SCOUT_HANG-2023-10-13-10-34-24
W/MIUIScout App(31798): Event:APP_SCOUT_HANG Thread:main backtrace:
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:717)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1074)W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:276)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at com.wongpiwat.trust_location.LocationAssistant$8.onResult(LocationAssistant.java:722)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
W/MIUIScout App(31798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
I/e.mobilebenerit(31798): Thread[5,tid=31817,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb400007ab1d6d000,peer=0x134c4600,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/e.mobilebenerit(31798):
I/e.mobilebenerit(31798): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
W/Looper  (31798): PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=31 plan=10:34:19.957 late=4ms wall=30006ms running=5ms runnable=1ms h=com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$CallbackHandler w=1 procState=-1
I/Choreographer(31798): Skipped 1815 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Looper  (31798): PerfMonitor doFrame : time=0ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=29994ms procState=-1 historyMsgCount=1 (msgIndex=1 wall=30006ms seq=31 running=5ms runnable=1ms late=4ms h=com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$CallbackHandler w=1)
```

I had try from the error or warning info and fixing some problem in
Flutter and upgrade the bug and error from the pubspec.yaml and upgrade the dep to the new version, EXCEPT for http and one_signal and something that connected with it (http : 0.13.6, onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.8)

Is there something I need to upgrade?

Comment: You can run -- 'flutter doctor' in command line then see the output, its alright? if any error then first fix that. After you can run -- 'flutter pub get' to get all the dependencies then debug it by running 'flutter run'

Comment: about the 'flutter doctor' I already try it and found one problem, and the problem is in the 'visual studio - develop windows app', is it necessary to connect the visual studio?, and  is it make some change to my code?.

Comment: For developing windows app its right that you have to install 'visual studio', Its necessary for windows app.

Comment: Okay I'll try my best, thanks for give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the usage of one of the methods or possibly a variable in the '[trust_location](https://pub.dev/packages/trust_location)' package, try checking it again. If indeed the package is problematic, consider replacing it with a similar package.

Comment: Firstly thanks for help me with my problem, from your answer I see you said that 'possibly a variable in the trust_location package', this 'trust_location' is it on the 'pubspec.yaml' dependencies, or something that I built to to make some method to get permission from user to show their current location, or something in 'gradle', or maybe something else, sorry to bother you cuz I am currently new on Flutter Dev and Dev problematic, and thanks again for trying to solve my problems.

Comment: Have you try https://pub.dev/packages/location or https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator ?, i guess trust_location isn't well maintained. You can take a look to both packages.